# How can I retrieve all the keys from a child from Realtime Database?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have issues trying to fetch the number (count) of how many keys my child has and to retrieve an array with all the keys.

Right now, I have 4 keys under the child "Notifications". Every time I try to retrieve the count of keys from that child, I don't know why, Firebase is returning the integer 49. Sometimes it will give me 48 or 56. This makes 0 sense because even if somehow I was getting all the keys from all childs, I would still have more or less than what it shows me.

After I run my code, only the most recent key is also displayed on my text field and refuses to show me all the keys as intended.

This is my code:

```
func retrieveNotifications() {
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let dataName = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let ref = databaseRef.child("User_Information").child("\(dataName)").child("Notifications")
    
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value , with: { (snapshot) in
            for notifications in snapshot.children {
                let snap = notifications as! DataSnapshot
                let key = snap.key
                let value = snap.value
                let count = snap.key.count
                
                if count > 0 {
                    self.notificationNumber.isHidden = false
                    self.noNewNotificationsMessage.isHidden = true
                    self.notificationsText.isHidden = false
                    self.clearButton.isHidden = false
                    self.notificationNumber.text = "\(count) notifications"
                    self.notificationsText.text = "\(key)"
                } else {
                    self.notificationNumber.isHidden = true
                    self.notificationsText.isHidden = true
                    self.clearButton.isHidden = true
                    self.noNewNotificationsMessage.isHidden = false
                }
            }
        })
}
```

I have looked at the code for hours, any help is very appreciated, maybe I am not seeing something obvious.

I have tried to everything I could think of at this point. Nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're:

1. Reading the notifications of the user.
2. Then looping over the notification.
3. Then **for each notification** you determine the **length of its key**

If you want to determine the number of child nodes under `Notifications`, that'd be something like:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value , with: { (snapshot) in
    let count = snapshot.childrenCount
    ...
```

Also see the [reference documentation for the `childrenCount` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#childrencount)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for my issue with the count. Very, very appreciated!